# How do I iterate over values of a multivalued field with entity_metadata_wrapper?

Tags: 7, entities

For instance, I have a taxonomy_term_reference field with cardinality -1. If one or more terms are selected, I can use this code:

```
  foreach ($wrapper->field_myterms as $t) {
    $terms[] = $t->name->value();
  }
```

But if the field has zero values selected, this code throws:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unable to get the data property name as the parent data structure is not set. in EntityStructureWrapper->getPropertyValue() (line 442 of sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc).
```

This happens in a preview form step while creating a custom entity. The entity has not yet been saved but I am showing a preview of the properties and field data by creating a temporary entity with this code:

```
$entity = entity_get_controller('ams_survey')->create($form_state['values']);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('ams_survey', $entity);
```

Comment: Have you tried `if (!empty($wrapper->field_myterms)) {`?

Comment: Yes - I tried that before and inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce this behaviour having used the following simple test:

1. Add a new article with no Tag terms, and note the nid (`field_tags` is a taxonomy term reference field with a cardinality of -1).
2. Run the following code:

   ```
   $node = node_load($nid);
   $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);

   foreach ($wrapper->field_tags as $item) {
     dpm($item);
   }
   ```

No debug messages are printed (as you'd expect), but I get no errors either.

The only thing I can think that might be causing the problem is that the entity in question was created *before* you added the `field_myterms` field. In that case there would be no entry in the field table for that entity, and it might cause some strange behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, Clive. I exported the article tags field and my custom field and the config arrays are almost identical, aside from my widget using select instead of autocomplete. The other difference about my situation is that I am trying to iterate over the field in a preview form step and the entity has not been saved yet. I'm adding the code to do this to the original question now.

Comment: Ah ok I think that makes sense then...when you add a term the field is set up inside the wrapper by the entity module. When you _don't_, that member isn't initialised and looping over a non-traversable wrapper object will throw an exception. A simple way around it might be to just add a `try{ } catch(EntityMetadataWrapperException $e) {}` block around the code; that way you won't get the error, and you can even handle it in some way if you feel it's necessary.

Comment: Ah - that makes sense. How could I force the wrapper to set up the empty field(s)?

Comment: Not sure, I've been racking my brains about that one too. I'll have a play with some code and let you know if I come up with anything

Comment: Just a note: you don't have to load the entity before passing it into the `entity_metadata_wrapper`. You can just pass the entity id. `node_load($nid)` in the sample code is superfluous.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in this file: /sites/all/modules/entity/includes/entity.wrapper.inc

Whenever a field_foobar->value() is called, and the field isn't set, then the class throws an Exception.  That is just silly, because having an empty field isn't an error.

Inside that field, when checking to see if a field is empty, it uses this code:

```
$data = $this->dataAvailable() ? $this->value() : NULL;
```

But using "if ($wrapper->field->foobar->dataAvailable())" before each echo of the value is aggravating.  Sigh, why can't things in Drupal ever be simple?

Comment: `dataAvailable()` is protected, so I'm not sure you can do even that. And I echo your sentiment, @user19317.

Answer (score 0):

For those who came later. Based on this page [Entity metadata wrappers](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/entity-api/entity-metadata-wrappers#working-with-lists), you should use `->getIterator()`:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
foreach ($wrapper->field_taxonomy_terms->getIterator() as $delta => $term_wrapper) {
  // $term_wrapper may now be accessed as a taxonomy term wrapper.
  $label = $term_wrapper->name->value();
}
```